# Google apps script Error “Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.”

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc, mysql-workbench

I tried to connect with my MySQL database from google apps script but I get this message error.

[image: error message]

(1) I have authorize all ip address
(2) I use the ip address in url instead of hostname

Please can someone help me ! thank you

Comment: Can you, please, share the full error message with possibly a stack trace as well?

Comment: Mysql version??

Comment: MySql workbench 8.0